# If Is Evil - Nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm using Nginx 1.6.2. I read that if () is evil and it's not good using it so I need a bit help, because I can't do what I want without using if(). I will post the rules I have with if and would ask if somebody could help me and tell me how to not use if () and use something else and get the same result.

```
# REDIRECT NON-WWW TO WWW.
if ($http_host != "www.site.eu") {
    rewrite ^ http://www.site.eu$request_uri permanent;
}

# REMOVE INDEX FILES FROM URL FOR SEO PURPOSE.
if ($request_uri ~ "/index.php") {
    rewrite ^ /$1 permanent;
}

# REMOVE ANY MULTIPLE SLASHES IN THE URL.
if ($request_uri ~* "\/\/") {
    rewrite ^/(.*) $scheme://$host/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: First block should be replaced by separate server block. Second and third are not needed in 99% of cases

Comment: @Alexey Ten - What do you mena, which first block should be replaced by separete server block and what do you mean by separete server block, server {}? Would it be possible to give me the right rules as I didn't understand what you mean?

Comment: Your first rule should be handled as per Alexey Ten's suggestion. The second rule is a bit meaningless and needs to be restructured under the "normal config" server block from Alexey if really needed. The third rule is handled by nginx automatically and not required at all.

Answer (score 3):

First rule should be replaced with separate server blocks

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    # normal config
}
```

Other `if`s usually are not necessary. Just don't generate links with `index.php` and you will not need to strip it.

Answer (score 1):

[In the official wiki introduction](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) it says that there are some cases which are ok. Have a look at this quote:

> The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in location
>   context are:
>
> return ...; rewrite ... last;

At the end of the introduction there is an example which also features a rewrite command. So your code looks ok, too.

EDIT: You should also have a look at [how the if works](http://agentzh.blogspot.de/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this block

```
# REMOVE INDEX FILES FROM URL FOR SEO PURPOSE.
if ($request_uri ~ "/index.php") {
    rewrite ^ /$1 permanent;
}
```

with this

```
location ~ ^/index.php/(.*[^/])$ { return 301 $scheme://$host/$1/$is_args$args; }
location ~ ^/index.php/(.*)/$ { return 301 $scheme://$host/$1/$is_args$args; }
```

I also don't think you need to worry about the last rule for double // because nginx by default automatically takes care of that before it even gets to the point of matching location blocks

Comment: Thanks for that, the last rule is needed because if it's not there the double // still appears. For some reason nginx won't remove it automatically like you said.